# getting html5 boilerplate .htaccess file to work on dreamhost site

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dreamhost

Completely new to Apache.

Trying to remove ".html" extension from urls by adding the following lines (found [here](http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/)):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

to this (including ^ those lines now):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

# Enable the `FollowSymLinks` option if it isn't already.
# Options +FollowSymlinks

# If your web host doesn't allow the `FollowSymlinks` option, you need to comment it out or remove it, and then uncomment the `Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` line, but be aware of the performance impact.
# Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteBase /

# RewriteOptions <options>

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:https]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:http]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

But the .html extensions remain in the visible urls.

I couldn't find any info on whether Dreamhost allows `FollowSymLinks`, but I tried it enabled, as well as `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`, I also tried disabling `RewriteBase /` and even removing the mod rewrite if statement. I'm placing the file in my website's root directory, and tried placing it in the parent folder to that too with no results. Anybody have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

[The full .htaccess is here.](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess)

### Solved:

I still don't know why the above code didn't work, but I just used the code from [Dreamhost's wiki](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Htaccess_tricks#Removing_the_file_extension) instead:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index$ http://Your_Site_Url_Goes_Here.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://Your_Site_Url_Goes_Here.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.+)\.html\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ http://Your_Site_Url_Goes_Here.com/$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /$1.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Be mindful that the above code may cause new problems, as it is causing one of my pages to return a 403 Forbidden error, but I think that's a whole other problem irrelevant to my original question so I consider this a solve and will fix the above code when I find a solution elsewhere.

Symlinks seem to have been irrelevant.

`.htaccess` file goes in >mySite.com directory, rather than the directory that contains this directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DreamHost wiki has a guide on [how to use Apache redirects and rewrites](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Mod_rewrite#Redirects_and_rewrites). The guide mentions FollowSimylinks

You should also check the Apache error logs to see what fails (and edit your question to be more specific about the result you see in the browser).

Comment: My `/var/log/apache2/error_log` file hasn't received an error since 2013... When does my `.htaccess` officially "fail" and send errors to `error_log`? For example I edit `.htaccess` locally, then load it up to my site with FTP client, so it's not being executed locally... does it fail when I visit my site? Or is there a way that I can compile locally? If so, how? I'm using Sublime and/or vim to edit it.

Comment: Solved my original problem but would be nice if you/someone else could expand here on how to utilize Apache error logs (or link to a good explanation) for posterity.